# Posicionamento de div

Tags: html5, css3

Tou a tentar fazer uma brincadeira com css e html5 deste tipo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que esta a dar varios problemas porque

1. A `div (content)`principar nao está a ocupar toda a altura e largura da pagina.
2. O Posicionamento da `div (central)`  aparenta estar no meio mas quando passa para ecrãs maiores isso não acontece .
   Codigo

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
body {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
#centro {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20%;
  margin-bottom: 15%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
section p {
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Comic Sans MS;
  font-size: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}
footer {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #8AC007;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <section id="centro">
    <p>
      Teste
    </p>
  </section>
  <footer>
    Teste
  </footer>
</div>
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Cole seu código aqui também, para facilitar a análise do pessoal.

Comment: Já meti obrigado pela dica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, para conseguir centralizar a `div (central)` na pagina, você terá que aplicar um `position: absolute` na mesma, então necessariamente a `div (content)` não pode ter um `position: static`, neste caso terá de trabalhar com `relative`, `absolute` ou `fixed`

Para fazer a `div (central)` ocupar toda a pagina, então você deve fazer o `html` e o `body` também ocuparem toda a pagina, afinal o `height: 100%`é relativo ao tamanho do elemento pai.

```css
html, body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#content {
  background-color: gainsboro;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#central {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
}

#central p {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 120px;
  line-height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 36px;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;  
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="central">
    <p>Texto</p>
  </div>
  <footer>
    Texto
  </footer>
</div>
```

O truque para centralizar a `div(central)` é ancorar ela no topo e no final, para isto você vai precisar do `top: 0px` e `bottom: 0px`, mas ao fazer isto e deixar o `height: auto`, a `div(central)` vai ocupar todo o espaço da `div(content)`, um efeito semelhante a um `height: 100%`, então se especificamos um `height` e colocamos `margin: auto`, as margens irão crescer até a posição do `top: 0px` e o `bottom: 0px`;

Comment: deu certo mas o problema e que o `footer` fica em cima não no lugar dele em baixo

Comment: Tenta colocar o footer com `position: absolute` e `bottom: 0px`

Comment: O exemplo que coloquei acima, o footer está na parte de baixo.